How to use websockets or Server sent requests with multiple servers and multiple different webapps
https://imgur.com/a/whLz2kG
I have a react app allows a user to find available people. When they click on a button for example i want them to be shown a waiting page. I then send a request to my backend api that i want to find a person. This backend then needs to send a request to another backend server to store this person and their status in a database and then update another webapp to use this information (this webapp is connected to the second backend). Then on the other webapp someone (part of an organisation) can accept the person or reject them. When this happens i want to then update this in the database and send a response back to the initial backend and then to the user on react app eventually. (see image above ^^ if explanation is not that clear)
Basically i want a user to find available person and wait until someone on another webapp accepts or rejects.
Im not 100% sure how to approach this situation. I have never used websockets or SSEs but i have thought about using them but im not too sure how i would implement it in this situation. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
